# Why is my psycopg2 not working with python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to run a simple python script to connect to my local postgresl db. I am on a mac and after doing a `pip install psycopg2` and `pip install psycopg2-binary` I still get a module not found error in my simple script.

Python 3.8.1

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

**test.py**:

```
import psycopg2
```

Comment: You have to install it for your Python version a well. `pip3 install...` or `python3 -m pip install...`

Comment: Check the output of your installs and make sure they actually installed. Also since you are on a mac, make sure that you actually installed it in your python 3.8.1 system. Macs come with Python 2 preinstalled on them it's very easy to use the wrong one, or install a library to the wrong one.

Comment: This worked, Thank you!!